# Find biggest order by client in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for some elegant solution to find preferred channel by client.
As an input we get list of transactions, which contains clientid, date, invoice_id, channel and amount. For every client we need to find preferred channel based on amount.

In case some specific client has 2 channels - outcome should be RANDOM among those channels.

Input data:

```
Clients ID |  Date      | Invoice Id | Channel | Amount
-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------
Client #1  | 01-01-2020 | 0000000001 | Retail  |  90
Client #1  | 07-01-2020 | 0000000002 | Website | 180
Client #2  | 08-01-2020 | 0000000003 | Retail  |  70
Client #2  | 09-01-2020 | 0000000004 | Website |  70
Client #3  | 10-01-2020 | 0000000005 | Retail  | 140
Client #4  | 11-01-2020 | 0000000006 | Retail  |  70
Client #4  | 13-01-2020 | 0000000007 | Website |  30
```

Desired output:

```
Clients ID |  Top-Channel
-----------+-----------------
Client #1  | Website     >> website 180 > retail 90
Client #2  | Retail      >> random choice from Retail and Website
Client #3  | Retail      >> retail 140 > website 0
Client #4  | Retail      >> retail 70 > website 30
```

Usually to solve such tasks I do some manipulations with GROUP BY, add a random number which is less than 1, and many other tricks. But most probably, there is a better solution.

This is for Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Your sample data only has one row per client/channel combination.  However, the description of the problem suggests that you might need aggregation.  That is worth clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the totals, then you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you need to aggregate to get the totals, the same approach works with aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.client_id, t.channel, sum(amount) as total_amount,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by sum(amount) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.client_id, t.channel
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So keeping your desired output in mind, I wrote the following T-SQL without using group by

```
declare @clients_id int =1
declare @clients_id_max int = (select max(clients_id) from random)
declare  @tab1 table (clients_id int, [Top-Channel] nvarchar(10), amount int)
declare @tab2 table (clients_id int, remarks nvarchar (100))
while @clients_id <= @clients_id_max
begin
if ((select count(*) from random where clients_id =@clients_id) > 1)
begin
insert into @tab2 select top 1 a.clients_id, a.channel +' '+ cast (a.amount as nvarchar(5)) +' ; '+ b.channel +' '+ cast (b.amount as nvarchar(5))  as remarks
from random a, random b  where a.clients_id =@clients_id and a.clients_id = b.clients_id   and a.channel <> b.channel
order by a.amount desc
end
else
begin
insert into @tab2 select  a.clients_id, a.channel +' '+ cast (a.amount as nvarchar(5))  as remarks
from random a, random b  where a.clients_id =@clients_id and a.clients_id = b.clients_id
order by a.amount desc
end
insert into @tab1 select top 1 clients_id, Channel as [Top-Channel], amount from random where clients_id = @clients_id order by amount desc
set @clients_id = @clients_id +1
end
select a.clients_id, a.[Top-Channel], b.Remarks from @tab1 a join  @tab2 b on a.clients_id = b.clients_id
```

[Query Output
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RzcV.jpg ]

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select distinct ID,FIRST_VALUE(Channel) over (partition by ID order by amount desc,NEWID())
from Table1
```